# Best practice for dynamically rendering element outside of template

Tags: templates, meteor, iron-router

What is the best way of toggling the presence of some element (represented by a template) that is a direct child of `<body>`?

I'm talking about a **modal box, notification, light-box etc.** that is triggered either by some user event or by a route.

*Examples: Dialog for newsletter sign-up that is shown after a user clicks a button. Overlay for content editing that is triggered by appending `/edit` to the item's route*

**Edit:**

The first solution I though of was using Session to control state and then lining up all the application's modals and messages inside `#if` statements at the end of my main layout template like this:

```
<template name="layout">
  <!-- yields and stuff -->

  {{#if isActiveModal 'editArticle'}}{{> editArticle}}{{/if}}
  {{#if ...
</template>
```

The problem is modularity; if a teammate is working inside some page template and needs to display a specific message or dialog, he or she has to edit the main layout to add it. I would have liked some easy way of conditionally appending a template to `<body>`.

Should be possible with the tools at hand, shouldn't it?

Comment: Currently, it's not easily done without some added uglyness to your code, check out my answer to this similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955055/modal-bootstrap-disapear-with-change-event-meteor/19965346#19965346 This "pattern" is used in the "parties" Meteor core example so it's the official workaround until the new rendering engine is ready. So to toggle the presence of a dialog box, you currently have to use a Session variable and animation (fading in/out) is a pain to integrate seamlessly. In a near future we'll be able to rely on classical jQuery class toggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I posted the question, Blaze has become more sophisticated. Elements can now be rendered anywhere in the DOM while keeping a logical view hierarchy. See this discussion:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/most-useful-meteor-apis/1560/8

I've inserted the main outline below – the full thread also has code examples.

---

...

[Use] `Blaze.render` to output a template anywhere in the DOM – such as in a dimmable wrapper directly inside `<body>` – while maintaining a parent-child relationship between the view of the opening template and the view of the modal. This relationship is required for them to communicate directly.

(Bear in mind that a `Session` variable, among other limitations, can only hold serializable data...)

With the hierarchy intact, it's possible to set up shared reactivity between the modal and the background and call methods on the other, too. If we volunteered to use `Blaze.renderWithData`, then the two templates can even share the same data context!

Manually traversing the view hierarchy is pretty tedious, but with the `parent()` method from [aldeed:template-extension](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension), it isn't an issue.

Depending on whether one likes to use template instances as a 'view-model' or prefers to pass stuff around, reciprocal reactivity between the two templates can either be mediated by a `new ReactiveVar` assigned to a property on the parent template instance or view, or by a more retrieve-on-demand [TemplateVar](https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-template-var/).

The entire exercise with `Blaze.render` can be duly incapsulated by using tricks like block helper templates and keyword arguments, so that everything is kept declarative.

Answer (score 0):

I actually use bootbox throughout several of my Meteor apps and it works great and does not interfere with any of Meteor's rendering. You can use the normal `alert`, `confirm`, `prompt`, as well as a custom `dialog` function, in a non-blocking way. There is a smart package available:

> https://github.com/TimHeckel/meteor-bootboxjs

See some of my apps and smart packages for examples (grep for `bootbox.`):

- https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper/
- https://github.com/HarvardEconCS/turkserver-meteor/

Comment: It's a good answer, but the project doesn't use Bootstrap. I was looking for a general pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of the new template engine, you can work with the body tag as its own special template through `UI.body`:

```
meteor update --release template-engine-preview-10.1
```

HTML:

```html
<body>
  {{#with alert}}
    {{> modal}}
  {{/with}}
</body>

<template name="modal">
  <div class="modal">
    <a href="#" class="close">X</a>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  UI.body.alert = function() {
    return Session.get("modal-alert");
  };

  UI.body.events({
    "click .close": function() {
      Session.set("modal-alert", null);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but see the edit above. I think this is the same kind of solution.