# Meteor's Iron Router doesn't close modal dialog

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, iron-router, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Meteor and Iron Router, and I have a modal dialog that won't hide the backdrop when it gets dismissed. To be more accurate, I want that after clicking the dismiss button, the iron router will redirect to another page. The redirection code does work, but the backdrop stays visible. If I remove the routing line - the modal is dismissed and so does the backdrop.

Here is the modal's markup:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                This cannot be undone.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" id="confirm-yes-button">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the button that toggles the modal dialog:

```
<button type="button" id="delete-recipe-btn" data-target="#confirm-modal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger pull-right">Delete</button>
```

Here is the click event on the 'yes' button of the confirm modal dialog:

```
    'click #confirm-yes-button': function() {
    Recipes.remove(this._id);
    $('#confirm-modal').modal('hide');
    Router.go('/');
}
```

Why would the routing leave the backdrop visible?

Comment: try having modal backdrop inside your template like in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955055/modal-bootstrap-disapear-with-change-event-meteor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this, depending on exactly how you desire the behavior. If you want the modal to hide first, then change the page, you can use a callback on the modal's behavior.

```
'click #confirm-yes-button': function() {
    Recipes.remove(this._id);
    $('#confirm-modal')
        .on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
            Router.go('/');
        })
        .modal('hide');
}
```

As to your question of why the backdrop is visible - its complicated. The backdrop is only hidden once the "hide" animation completes, and changing the page interrupts/stops this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution would be to use jQuery methods to remove backdrop 
once the user has been redirected.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(){
    Router.go('/');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});
```

However to use this method you need have access to Accounts.login method which can be acquired by adding

> gwendall:auth-client-callbacks

package to your meteor project