# Issues with Router.go method greying out the routed page meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Hi I am trying to verify that the users correctly typed a password and once thats done I am using Router.go to route the user to an index page. everything works fine until I route the user to the index route I can see the page and the Meteor.userId() is passed but the whole template is greyed out and disabled. Not sure whats going on but think it may have something to do with with how I'm setting the route parameter. Any help greatly appreciated.

**Template**

```
Template.verifyPassword.events({

    'click #verifyPw': function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        $('#verifyPwModal').modal('show');
    },

    'click #check-password': function(){

        var digest = Package.sha.SHA256($('#password').val());

        Meteor.call('checkPassword', digest, function(error, result){

            if(result)
                console.log("Thats the correct Password")
        });

        $('#verifyPwModal').modal('hide');

        Router.go('index', {_id: Meteor.userId()});

    }
});
```

**Router.Js**

```
Router.configure({

 layoutTemplate: 'layout'

});

Router.route('/', {name: 'welcome'});

Router.route('/user/:_id',{
    name: 'index',
    data: function() {return Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id)}
});

Router.route('/unlock', {name: 'verifyPassword'});
```

Comment: Can you share the index template code?

Comment: thanks Stephen learnt it was the modal that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with modal dialog not closing. If anyone else have similar problem Check out this answer.

[Meteor's Iron Router doesn't close modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363375/meteors-iron-router-doesnt-close-modal-dialog)